# Voices begun suppress in all audio

Tags: audio

I don't understand, what had happened. All audio, produced by my computer, became bad. I can't describe the distortion nature precidely, but it looks like, that all voices became suppressed and echoed. Only voices. Even in double channel media. For example, youtube advertisments, or audio track recorded. Music sounds nearly perfect while voices singing or saying seem to be very quiet.

How can it be?

I can't even understand, how this distortion can even be made. Look like sophisticated AI is working, detecting only voice presence and dimming it selectively!

It is not frequency filtering!

I am using built-in audio from Gigabyte GA-B85M-D3H motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

Voice cancellation was turned on somehow. Didn't knew one exist:

[image]

**UDPATE**

This was turned on by occasional clicking on Karaoke:

[image]